# Empty in-app notification if open from the drop-down Android

Tags: bug, android-app

If I receive a notification (new comment or answer) and open the StackExchange application, the notification drawer is completely empty and I need to reopen the app.

Using StackExchange 1.0.71 and Android 5.1.1.

[image]